# A Good Example On How to Use BusterJs Resource Config Option?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, buster.js

I'm looking for a good example that shows how to use busterJS's `resource` property in the `buster.js` config file to include a .json file in a test case.

From the documentation:

> **resources**
>
> Additional resources that will be made available for test runs, but not explicitly loaded. Value is an array of resources. Resources are served from a context path on the server. To request a resource in your test runs, you need to scope resource paths with `buster.env.contextPath`. The resource /some/cookies.json can be requested as `jQuery.get(buster.env.contextPath + "/some/cookies.json")`;

[It also states:](http://busterjs.org/docs/configuration/#resource)

> A "resource" is something exposed on the server when you run browser
>   tests using buster-server and buster-test. Exposing the resource
>   `/something.json` allows you to request it in your tests using e.g.
>   `jQuery.ajax({ url: "something.json" });`.

And here's the example they give:

```
    config["Browser build tests"] = {
    environment: "browser",
    libs: ["lib/**.js"],
    resources: [
        "src/**.js",
        { path: "/mylib.min.js",
          combine: ["src/base.js", "src/dom.js"] }
    ],
    sources: ["/mylib.min.js"],
    tests: ["test/**.js"]
};
```

However, they don't give a solid example of using the JSON file in a unit test. When I've tried following their examples, jQuery throws a 404 when I try doing `jQuery.ajax({ url: "[my-file-name-here]" })`.

Has anyone ever successfully used this feature?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's supposed to work: https://gist.github.com/4554427 But I'm seeing weird responseText with this, so I need to look into why that happens...

Comment: Would you mind also elaborating on when it's appropriate to use a resource in your unit tests? Or what problem are they meant to solve?